# References on Mathematical Instanton bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am interested in learning about Mathematical Instanton bundles on Projective varieties and their moduli. The earliest paper that I can locate online is [This paper](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1982_4_15_2_365_0.pdf). Indeed there are several other papers after that. Is there any book or survey paper on Mathematical Instanton bundles which gives a systematic presentation  from its introduction to some of its recent developements? Which is a good place to start learning some basic things about these objects to prepare for more advanced areas on this topic?

Any suggestion from anyone is welcome.

Comment: If you can read french,  [this book](http://www.numdam.org/issue/AST_1980__71-72__1_0.pdf) (freely available) is still a good reference for the early developments of the theory, particularly for its relations with physics. After that, googling "instanton bundles" should give you an overview on the more recent work.

Comment: @abx, thank you very much for the reference. Is there any more recent lecture notes or video resources available on this topic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book [Okonek, Christian; Schneider, Michael; Spindler, Heinz. Vector bundles on complex projective spaces] is a very nice source, but it is a bit old, of course.